# Why the `libstdc++.so` compiled from source seems to be incorrect?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I try to compile `gcc` and `libstdc++`(as a part of `gcc`) from the source code.

With:

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc.git # mirror repo
$ cd gcc && md build && cd build
$ ../configure --enable-languages=c,c++,lto     \
    --enable-lto --prefix=/usr/local            \
    --enable-shared --enable-host-shared        \
    --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld                 \
    --enable-threads=posix                      \
    --enable-__cxa_atexit                       \
    --enable-gnu-indirect-function              \
    --disable-werror --enable-checking=release  \
    --disable-multilib --enable-linker-build-id \ 
    --with-linker-hash-style=gnu                \
    --disable-bootstrap --disable-libssp        \
    --enable-default-ssp
$ make all -j4 && make install
```

However, when I try to link `libQt6Core.so` into my project with the above compiler and libstdc++, `ld` complains like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/../lib64/libQt6Core.so: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4'
```

Also, I find:

```
$ strings /usr/local/lib64 | grep GLIBCXX # get libcxx api version
```

only gives:

```
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

But with system libstdc++ I can see string like `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` and so on.

So why my libstdc++ lib seems get something wrong?

Comment: How are you building and linking your project? Are you using `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: Installing important libraries this way is not a good idea.

Comment: You may have a system for which symbol versions are not enabled automatically. See `--enable-symvers` in the configure.html doc of libstdc++-v3. Try requesting `--enable-symvers=gnu` explicitly.